# What's the easiest method to change the namespace value using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, serialization, xml-namespaces

TL/DR: What's the easiest method to change the namespace value using `LINQ to XML`, say from `xmlns:gcs="clr-namespace:NsOne;assembly=AsmOne"` to `xmlns:gcs="clr-namespace:NsTwo;assembly=AsmTwo"`?

Why? because:

I serialized `Xaml` using `System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(myControl)`. I want to visualize this GUI appearance somewhere else (deserializing using `System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(raw)`), in another project.

**I don't want to link to the original assembly!**

I just need to change the namespace, so `XamlReader.Parse(raw)` won't throw an exception. I currently do it using regular-expressions **and it works**, but I don't like that method (e.g. if I have `xmlns:gcs="clr-namespace:NsOne;assembly=AsmOne"` inside a `CDATA`)

This is my serialized `Xaml`:

```
<FlowDocument PagePadding="5,0,5,0" AllowDrop="True"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:gcs="clr-namespace:NsOne;assembly=AsmOne"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <gcs:MyParagraph Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <gcs:MyParagraph.MetaData>
            <gcs:ParagraphMetaData UpdaterParagraphUniqueId="1" />
        </gcs:MyParagraph.MetaData>
        <Span>some text...</Span>
    </gcs:MyParagraph>
    <gcs:MyParagraph Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FFF0F0F0">
        <gcs:MyParagraph.MetaData>
            <gcs:ParagraphMetaData UpdaterParagraphUniqueId="2" />
        </gcs:MyParagraph.MetaData>
        <Span Foreground="#FF0000FF">some more text...</Span>
    </gcs:MyParagraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

(`MyParagraph` and `ParagraphMetaData` are custom types and they both exist at the source assembly and the destination assembly. `MyParagraph` inherits `WPF`'s `Paragraph`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(raw);
XNamespace fromNs = "clr-namespace:NsOne;assembly=AsmOne";
XNamespace toNs = "clr-namespace:NsTwo;assembly=AsmTwo";

// redefines "gcs", but doesn't change what namespace the elements are in
doc.Root.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xmlns + "gcs", toNs);

// this actually changes the namespaces of the elements from the old to the new
foreach (var element in doc.Root.Descendants()
                                  .Where(x => x.Name.Namespace == fromNs))
    element.Name = toNs + element.Name.LocalName;
```

Both portions are needed to result in XAML that's both correct and easily-readable, because the namespace of the elements is stored separately from the `xmlns` declarations in an `XDocument`. If you only change what "gcs" means, then it will write `xmlns` statements to keep the elements in their old namespace. If you only change what namespace the elements are in, then it will include `xmlns="clr-namespace:NsTwo;assembly=AsmTwo"` statements as necessary, and ignore `gcs` (which will still reference the old `NsOne`).