# Correct way to add a namespace to an element using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, soap, namespaces, xmldocument

I have to modify a incoming SOAP XML message to add a namespace to one of the elements so that the deserialisation will work. However when I add the xmlns attribute to the correct element, I get an error when I try to load the xml in to an XmlWriter via a stream (which I need to do to in my IClientMessageInspector implementation to replace the Message reply).

```
The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://www.example.com' within the same start element tag.
```

I have a work around, which is that after I've modifed the attribute, I reload the entire XML document from it's own OuterXML. This works for some reason, but makes me think there must be a 'correct' way to do this.

Here's a sample test that demonstrates the problem and my current solutions:

```
    [Test]    
    public void XmlNamespaceTest()
    {
        var originalXmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><TestElement><Child>thing</Child></TestElement>";
        var desiredXmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><TestElement xmlns=\"http://www.example.com\"><Child>thing</Child></TestElement>";

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(originalXmlString);
        Assert.That(originalXmlString, Is.EqualTo(doc.OuterXml));

        // Write this document via an XMLWriter
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
        doc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Flush();

        ms.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        var originalXmlViaXmlWriter = sr.ReadToEnd();

        Assert.That(originalXmlString, Is.EqualTo(originalXmlViaXmlWriter));

        // Add the namespace to the element
        ((XmlElement)doc.GetElementsByTagName("TestElement").Item(0))?.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.example.com");
        Assert.That(desiredXmlString, Is.EqualTo(doc.OuterXml));


        // Now attempt to write this modified xml via an XMLWriter
        ms.SetLength(0);
        xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ms);

        //Uncomment line below to fix the error.
        //doc.LoadXml(doc.OuterXml);

        doc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Flush();

        ms.Position = 0;
        sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        var modifedXmlViaXmlWriter = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Assert.That(desiredXmlString, Is.EqualTo(modifedXmlViaXmlWriter));
    }
```

Comment: If all the elements are withing the same namespace, you can set a default namespace for the whole XML document and skip setting the namespace for each node. Edit: I think this has nothing to do with `soap`. Consider removing that tag to grant a better audience for your question.

Comment: I just checked and the NamespaceUri property of XmlNode is read-only; so I think the easiest way to do this may be to create a new node using `CreateDocumentFragment()`, settings its InnerXml to `oldNode.InnerXml.Replace ("<TestElement>", "<TestElement xmlns=\"http://www.example.com\">")` and then calling `ReplaceChild` on the oldNode's parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/changing-namespace-declarations-in-an-xml-document) you can't change an elements namespace in an `XmlDocument`. This is also what @LocEngineer found in his comment. The referenced article mentions that the only way to do this is to save and reload the `XmlDocument`, which is exactly what you are doing.

If you are in a position to use `XDoxument` instead, it is possible. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20842852/4684493) answer for a solution.